# Using Syncfusion FileManager with NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I'm trying to use [Syncfusion Vue FileManager](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/file-manager/getting-started/) with NuxtJS.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <ejs-filemanager></ejs-filemanager>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { FileManagerPlugin } from '@syncfusion/ej2-vue-filemanager';

Vue.use(FileManagerPlugin);
export default {
  auth: false,
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-icons/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-inputs/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-popups/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-buttons/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-splitbuttons/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-navigations/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-layouts/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-grids/styles/material.css';
@import '../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-filemanager/styles/material.css';
</style>
```

This is my Sample-Page where I want to mess around with the FileManager. Unfortunately importing the `FileManagerPlugin` leads to the error in the Picture, when starting the server.

[image: Syncfusion Error]

I have added the following dependencies to my `package.json`:

```json
"@syncfusion/ej2-vue-filemanager": "^19.2.48",
"vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
```

I'm also receiving the error:

```sh
in ./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-vue-filemanager/src/file-manager/filemanager.component.js                                           friendly-errors 11:49:40  

"export 'Options' was not found in 'vue-class-component'
```

But without installing `vue-class-component` it doesn't start at all.

Comment: We already have a similar issue for Vue in Nuxt with the latest Syncfusion Vue packages and considered this as a bug. We expect that it will be included with our Volume 2, 2021 SP release by the mid of August.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [Github issue](https://github.com/syncfusion/ej2-vue-ui-components/issues/70#issuecomment-872237488), it looks like you need to install (at least)
`vue-class-component : 8.0.0-rc.1`

Answer (score 0):

Above reported issue has been resolved in our latest NuGet 19.2.55. Please update the packages to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with some source like a release page?

Comment: Download link for Volume 2 SP  is [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/168015/essential-studio-2021-volume-2-service-pack-release-v19-2-0-55-is-available-for-download)